# Transformer train a new tokenizer base on existing one

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers

In the following code

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-chinese")
tokenizer_new = tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(training_corpus, 50000, new_special_tokens = ['健康','医学','试剂盒',....])
```

where training_corpus is an iterator generating lines of text from hard drive chinese_medical.txt file

For readers who may not familiar with "bert-base-chinese", it is a single character tokenizer with "wordpiece" model as default

My question is

**tokenizer_new** has totally different indexing from **tokenizer**, for example

```
tokenizer.vocab['先'] #1044
tokenizer_new.vocab['先'] #5151
```

this makes continue training (i.e. train a Chinese medical specific BERT model) on model

```
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-chinese")
```

impossible. Because the indexing id for the same character is totally different in **tokenizer_new**

How to make the indexing for the same character fixed?

Comment: Why don't you train a new tokenizer and append the diff between the two vocabularies to the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

`train_new_from_iterator()` does not preserve the vocabulary.

https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter6/2:

> Even though we are going to train a new tokenizer, it’s a good idea to do this to avoid starting entirely from scratch. This way, we won’t have to specify anything about the tokenization algorithm or the special tokens we want to use; our new tokenizer will be exactly the same as GPT-2, and the only thing that will change is the vocabulary, which will be determined by the training on our corpus.